# Stop browser from trimming whitespace

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Not 100% sure what is going on, but I think the browser (Chrome) is trimming the whitespace.  Running a javascript repl the following outputs foo.name with the whitespace.

```
var foo = {
    name: "test     test"
}
```

Running this in a Chrome console, the whitespace is trimmed.

Any ideas how to stop that?

Thanks

Comment: figured it out.  addding `white-space: pre` to the css solved it.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with FF ...? What has CSS to do with the console?

Comment: @Teemu you are correct, firefox doesn't reproduce this in the console.  It does in an html page though.

Comment: Maybe you've to be clearer on your question then?  Running that JS in a browser shows nothing ... Please add the real code you have.

Comment: @Teemu I have figured it out. thanks

Comment: this is a bug in the current version of chrome - there was another question about it recently

Comment: And the [actual bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516989) - was fixed towards the end of august - hopefully be in an update soon.